# Why isn't the number gotten from this random code generator function not being saved on the DB?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate a random redeem code for when a user purchases one of my products.

The problem is that once the random code exists and the GetRandomRedeemCode function generates a new code, it won't get saved by Django in the DB. What could be the issue?

This is the code that gets called whenever a new order is placed:

```
def CompleteOrder(request):
    order_qs = Purchase.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs:
        specific_order = order_qs[0]
        for order in specific_order.product_purchased.all():
            order.item.purchased_by.add(request.user)
        specific_order.ordered = True
        specific_order.total_price = specific_order.get_total()
        *specific_order.redeem_code = GetRandomRedeemCode()*
        specific_order.save()
        return redirect("OrderCompletedSuccessURL")
```

And this is the GetRandomRedeemCode() function that gets called to create a random code and to check if the random code is already in the DB, ie. uniqueness.

```
def GetRandomRedeemCode():
    random_num = str(random.randint(10000000,99999999))
    if Purchase.objects.filter(redeem_code=random_num).exists():
        GetRandomRedeemCode()
    else:
        return random_num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *return* the recursive call:

```
def GetRandomRedeemCode():
    random_num = str(random.randint(10000000, 99999999))
    if Purchase.objects.filter(redeem_code=random_num).exists():
        return GetRandomRedeemCode()  # 🖘 return the result
    else:
        return random_num
```

You might however better use a `while` loop here:

```
def GetRandomRedeemCode():
    random_num = str(random.randint(10000000, 99999999))
    while Purchase.objects.filter(redeem_code=random_num).exists():
        random_num = str(random.randint(10000000, 99999999))
    return random_num
```